# Разработка на заказ с использованием GPL

Tags: лицензирование

Разрабатываю для заказчика ПО, в нем используется библиотека, идущая под GPL. То есть я обязан предоставить исходники ПО заказчику.

Он, в свою очередь, планирует продавать программу другой организации. Возможно ли для него не предоставлять этой организации исходники?

Comment: Лицензия именно GPL, а не, допустим, LGPL? Программа физически отдаётся или как сервис может работать (тогда важно GPL 2 или GPL 3 версия)?

Comment: Вот так написано на сайте разработчика библиотеки:

The SOFTWARE may be used according to Free Software GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2, or (at your option) any later version, with special exception to permit linking with some Open Source Third Party libraries set out below.

Программа отдается полностью, физически

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, читайте условия лицензии. Если исходники не идут вместе с программой, то он обязан предоставить их по запросу (по крайней мере, так было когда-то).

Comment: @evgensl, представьте себе, именно для **доступности исходников для всех** все это (GNU и проч. freeware) и затевалось.

Такой вот взгляд у людей на то, как правильно должна быть жизнь устроена.

Comment: Да, я бы и не против, но к заказчику с такими словами идти смысла нет :) Вот и ищу какое-нибудь компромиссное решение

Comment: @evgensl, можно купить лицензию для коммерческого использования аналогичной закрытой библиотеки.